# How to get the size of the result of a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, explain, query-cache

How do you get the size (in bytes) of the result of a SQL query, in MySQL 5.6?

`EXPLAIN` will return the number of fetched rows, but not their size.

My aim is to evaluate common queries to know a lower bound value for `query_cache_limit` so that they can be served by the Query Cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way.

- `EXPLAIN` gives you an estimation; do not count on it being exact.
- The number of bytes in a resultset is not directly available.  And attempts to estimate will be fraught with errors.
- The structure of the QC is another variable -- there is overhead to take into account.
- Since *every* row for a table in the QC is purged when *any* write to the table occurs, the QC is rarely useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

The slowlog has information like `Bytes_sent: 28517325` for each query.  However, I do not know whether it is just the size of the result set or that plus networking overhead.